# Why do I get a "Permission Denied" error when importing an obj file?

Tags: import

I'm extremely new to Blender. I literally just downloaded it, I was trying to import a .obj file however when I try I get the error message you see in the title. Any way to get around this? please help. Thanks.
I have the steam version.

Comment: Hi Anzour, welcome to Blender SE! Do you have read permission for the .obj file you're trying to import? Also, what operating system and Blender version (Help > Splash Screen) are you using?

Comment: Hopefully this'll help give some idea as to whats going on, I have Blender 2.74 and Windows 8.1 I was trying to import a model I created for an online game called Roblox, I created it in Roblox Studio and exported it as a .obj file. I stored it in my doc folder. I had watched several tutorials on rendering models before downloading Blender and I followed the steps to the letter but I was hit with the error and stopped from there.

Comment: I suspect Catlover2 is correct when he suggests that this is a permissions issue, and not a Blender issue. A good starting point is to . use the "help and support" facility in Windows, and review topics containing the phrase "administrator token" and "administrator".

Comment: All I can think of is that somehow you don't have read permission for the file. To check that, right-click the .obj file in Windows Explorer, click Properties, click the Security tab, and select your username in the "Group or user names" pane. If at least the Read box is not checked, then you don't have read permission. As brasshat points out, if this is the problem, it really has nothing to to with Blender.

Comment: All permissions are allowed, this is weird. Maybe this'll help, this is the exact error that comes up http://gyazo.com/d2fdc9b2caf6d415cd3e09e1472ec20d

Comment: Since it's showing the error for the directory that contains the file and not for the file itself, try copying the file to another directory. Also, perhaps have a look at the permissions of the Roblox directory; maybe the program that created it gave it weird permissions.

Comment: The folder throwing the error is your Roblox folder. Navigate to your documents folder, right click on the Roblox folder, and select properties at the bottom of the menu, and in the dialog box which appears, click on the "security" tab. If there is a line in the "Group or user names" panel which corresponds to your user name, Anzour, click on that, and make sure that in the permissions window at the bottom, the Anzour has write permissions for Roblox. My hunch is that it does not. For help, from the "help and support options", search for "change folder permissions".

Comment: You may have good reasons for using the Steam version, but frankly, you might be well advised to switch to the direct download version of Blender, either in the installed version, or as a zip file.

Comment: It worked thanks, I moved over the file to a different directory and everything loaded. Thanks for the help guys.

Comment: Glad it worked! @brasshat What do you think that using the Steam version of Blender has to do with this? If the issue is with permissions, I don't quite see how a different version of Blender would behave any differently...

Comment: @catlover2, I don't know whether the steam version of blender has anything to do with the permissions issue, or not. I have never used the steam version, always choosing to download from the native Blender.org site. But on a couple of other forums, I have noticed that people who get software (not Blender, in those cases) from Steam seem to have more problems, and less common problems than those who do not. In the case. of problems with blender, it seems to me that getting it via direct download removes one possible locus at which problems can affect the experience.  Basically, bias on my part.

Comment: I have the exact same problem here. I moved the files to a different directory and still am getting the error. All permissions are granted. Is this a bug?

Answer (score 2):

You are getting this error because your user doesn't have permission to read the file. In your specific case, there dosen't seem to be a problem with the permissions of the file itself but rather with its containing directory.

- To view or change permissions, right-click the file in Windows Explorer, click Properties, click the Security tab, and select your username in the "Group or user names" pane.
- One workaround that doesn't involve fiddling with permissions is to copy the file to somewhere else with Windows explorer.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem. I don't know if it's windows or the program that exported the file that messed up the access rights. After exporting the same object with the same program to the same directory, but under a different name the problem was solved. I just renamed the files to the name I originally used and it still worked. Really weird.