# Can not open .OBJ file - Permissions Denied

Tags: import

Similar to [THIS](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/33105/why-do-i-get-a-permission-denied-error-when-importing-an-obj-file) question, which has no definitive answer, I am unable to import an .OBJ file into Blender.

[image]

As you can see in the photo, the directory that is being held hostage is: C:\\Users\\Fiver\\Desktop.I am not sure why this DIR is even being referenced, as the .exe is being launched from a totally different location, and the .OBJ file is not located in C:\\Users\\Fiver\\Desktop. (why this dir is referenced is strange, and also it is strange that there are TWO backslashes in this path).

The permissions to the file, and its folders are all set to ALLOW, for all users. I can easily open this file with OPEN3D without permissions issues.

Is this a known bug?

Using Blender 2.78 on Windows7 64 bit.

Comment: Does this happen with just this specific obj file? Have you tried importing other obj files? Please try the following, 1- import another obj file from the same location. 2- import this specific obj file from different location.

Comment: I can open other obj files from same location, but can not open the one I want, regardless of where it is stored.

Comment: Then could you provide a link to this obj file to be able to help you?

Comment: @Tak https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B_fCZJv3NQ_nbjNZYlBwSEwzeFk

Comment: The error message suggests the importer is searching for materials in the "Fiver" path, rather than the obj file itself.

Comment: the only thing I can think of that has anything to do with that is that I am using Dexpot which creates numerous desktops in Windows, however as stated in the comments above, I can easily open a different .obj file from same location.

Comment: @KalamalkaKid I've tried importing the obj file you provided it was imported successfully with no errors as shown here http://pasteall.org/blend/index.php?id=45095

Comment: thank you, I can open the file, but it does not solve the issue. It seems the issue is from .OBJ files I am converting from MESH files in XNALara. I tired another Mesh-->OBJ file and i get the same error when trying to import into Blender. I am going to need to figure this out. I am curious why your Blender opens the file, but not my Blender.

Comment: **Line 1** of the obj file `mtllib C:\Users\Fiver\Desktop 3\Popori_F_Event-02a_08_00\NEW.mtl`  .  (Material file for the obj file) This will be a setting that can be changed in whatever the program is you are using for obj export.

Comment: @batFINGER thanks for your reply, but im not sure what the texture map file (MTL) has to do with why i cant open this in blender. ?

Comment: That's what the error message is telling you..  `mtl = open(mtlpath, 'rb')` the import script is trying to open that file and getting a permission denied error.

Comment: I see. So how do i fix this? The permissions for the MTL file are wide open for all users

Comment: http://www.tombraiderforums.com/showpost.php?s=1f6504dc4398e0cce78e6d3ac3301c1a&p=6495118&postcount=2

Comment: @batFINGER  not sure where this is going. "you need to copy the folders for the models used in the scene to the same location as the exported .obj file", There are no folders. There is one folder with ALL the files. The other user above was able to open the OBJECT file on its own without any other material. Why is that?

Comment: I'm on ubuntu and can import obj ok without materials/textures  , with warnings, as that file path doesn't exist, assume same for @Tak on whatever OS he's on.  It appears you do have that path and your OS is spitting the dummy with permission denied.  Could try editing the path in the obj file with a text editor, to a non existent path, or as suggested in forum post copy materials to same folder as obj and if needed edit material path accordingly.

Comment: I'm on both windows 7 and macOS and I get the same warning as @batFINGER , and there is a warning in the import `Material not found MTL: 'C:\\Users\\Fiver\\Desktop'` so as batFINGER suggested try editing that path in the obj file which is found in the first line of the obj file `mtllib C:\Users\Fiver\Desktop 3\Popori_F_Event-02a_08_00\NEW.mtl` edit it and make it point to the correct location where the material is found.

Comment: @tak The 'NEW.mtl' file is already in C:\Users\Fiver\Desktop 3\Popori_F_Event-02a_08_00\. When i import the OBJ file in Blender I can see the 'NEW.mtl' file right below the OBJ file in teh BLender import window, so its in the same DIR

Comment: @KalamalkaKid make sure that you the current user has full permissions in this specific path and mtl file.

Comment: @batFINGER editing the path in the obj file with a text editor, to a non existent path did not work either.

Comment: moving the entire DIR to a folder on C drive worked. perhaps it was the space ?

Comment: No, it looks like a permission as mentioned before.

Comment: ok well, i still dont understand why its a permission issue considering all the folders, files, and directories are all available to all users & admins. In any case, thanks for your help.