# Blender cannot read file, permission denied

Tags: error

just downloaded blender, but i cant open any files in blender, it just says cannot read file: permission denied. I have all permissions, tried running it as admin and madee sure folder was read/writeable. I tried uninstalling and downloading from steam instead, still nothing. I tried different folders, different harddrives, no luck.

Thanks, Herm.

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/84602/cannot-save-blend-files-permission-denied https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/91958/windows-10-blender-cannot-open-write-save-on-c https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/33105/why-do-i-get-a-permission-denied-error-when-importing-an-obj-file

Comment: how do ypu try to open the files? What kind of files do you try to read? Please be more specific

Comment: You didn't even state what OS you're on...